# Javascript functions trigger in Google inspects feature, but not otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
//Overlay mobile menu open
$('#burger-icon').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  document.getElementById('fp-menu').style.height = "100%";
  let overlay_content = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay-content")[0];
  let pipe = overlay_content.querySelector(".pipe");

  let contact = document.querySelector("#sidebar-leftButton");
  let case_studies = document.querySelector("#sidebar-rightButton");
  if (screen.width < 1000) {

    let overlay_contentA = document.querySelectorAll(".overlay a");

    for (i = 0; i < overlay_contentA.length; i++) {
      overlay_contentA[i].style.color = "white";
    }

    //changes the social icons to white if in mobile view.
    document.getElementById('instagram').src = "instagram_white.svg";
    document.getElementById('linkedin').src = "linkedin_white.svg";
    document.getElementById('twitter').src = "twitter_white.svg";

    //gets rid of the pipe in menu that is visible for the desktop version
    //removes sidetabs while in overlay menu
    pipe.style.display = "none";
    contact.style.display = "none";
    case_studies.style.display = "none";

    //changes how the elements are displayed when overlay is triggered
    $('#fp-menu .news').removeClass("col-sm-2");
    $('#fp-menu .portfolio').removeClass("col-sm-3");
    $('#fp-menu #social').removeClass("col-sm-6");
  }
});

function closeOverlayMenu() { //closes the overlay mobile menu
  // e.stopPropagation();
  $('#fp-menu').animateCss('slideUp');
  $('#fp-menu').css('height', 0);

  let overlay_content = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay-content")[0];
  let pipe = overlay_content.querySelector(".pipe");
  let contact = document.querySelector("#sidebar-leftButton");
  let case_studies = document.querySelector("#sidebar-rightButton");

  let overlay_contentA = document.querySelectorAll(".overlay a");

  for (i = 0; i < overlay_contentA.length; i++) {
    overlay_contentA[i].style.color = "black";
  }
  //changes icons to black on slide up of overlay
  document.getElementById('instagram').src = "instagram.svg";
  document.getElementById('linkedin').src = "linkedin.svg";
  document.getElementById('twitter').src = "twitter.svg";

  //restores elements of the original homepage that were hidden for overlay
  pipe.style.display = "block";
  contact.style.display = "block";
  case_studies.style.display = "block";

  $('#fp-menu .news').addClass("col-sm-2");
  $('#fp-menu .portfolio').addClass("col-sm-3");
  $('#fp-menu #social').addClass("col-sm-6");
};

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onresize = function() {
  closeOverlayMenu();
};

//overlay mobile  menu close
$('#closebtn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#fp-menu').animateCss('slideUp');
  $('#fp-menu').css('height', 0);


  //if overlay mobile menu is down, close it by clicking the X
  if (screen.width < 1000) {
    closeOverlayMenu();
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll("#social"));
  }

});
```

```css
//overlay menu styling
 .overlay {
 height: 0;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 999;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-color: #000000;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 transition: 0.5s;
 }
 .overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
  margin-top: 90px;

  .row{
   padding: 50px 30px 50px 30px;
   .column{
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
   }
  }
  img {
   width: 50px;
  }
  div {
   padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
  }
 }

 .overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
 }
 .overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
 }
 #closebtn {
  display:block;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  font-size: 60px;

 }
 #social{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  a {
   padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
  }

 }
 #fp-menu{
  display: block;
  color: $menu_black;
 }
 .pipe{
  display: block;
  transition: 0.4s;
 }
```

```html
<div id="fp-menu" class="overlay">
  <div id="closebtn" style="color: white;">X</div>
  <div class="column overlay-content">
    <!-- <div class="column"> -->
    <div class="col-sm-2 news">
      <a href="https://news.co.uk/">NEWS</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1 pipe">
      |
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 portfolio">
      <a href="https://production.co.uk/">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>
    <div id="social" class="col-sm-6">

      <a href="https://www.instagram.com"> <img id="instagram" src='instagram.svg' /></a>

      <a href="https://www.linkedin.com"> <img id="linkedin" src='linkedin.svg' /></a>

      <a href="https://twitter.com"> <img id="twitter" src='twitter.svg' /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the weirdest thing, I've got 1 function that is to trigger under 2 conditions: when the window is resized and when the exit button is clicked.

This relates to an overlay menu that's actually intended for mobile users.

The functions work as they are supposed to, in both cases, when I have the inspection console open in chrome. However, when I close this and return to the normal browser window, the functions cease to execute.

On the mobile it is fine. I have only encountered this problem on the desktop/laptop (as I tried it on different desktops [iMacs] and 2 laptops [Macbooks, but the type of hardware I don't think matters]).

Currently the icons in the "#social" div are not being changed to white, which is what I expect to happen when opened, and when closed, they return to black. They are staying black throughout the execution.

Has anyone ever experienced this before? This is related to a Wordpress platform site. Totally custom built, no themes.

Please let me know if this description helps. If any code is needed, please let me know.

Ps: I thought it was a caching problem, on the terminals or on the server, and I cleared the cache on both but the issue still persists.

```
function closeOverlayMenu(){//closes the overlay mobile menu
    $('#fp-menu').animateCss('slideUp');
    $('#fp-menu').css('height', 0);

    let overlay_content = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay-content")[0];
    let pipe = overlay_content.querySelector(".pipe");
    let contact = document.querySelector("#sidebar-leftButton");
    let case_studies = document.querySelector("#sidebar-rightButton");

    let overlay_contentA = document.querySelectorAll(".overlay a");

    for (i = 0; i < overlay_contentA.length; i++) {
        overlay_contentA[i].style.color = "black";
    }
    //changes icons to black on slide up of overlay
    document.getElementById('instagram').src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mvt-hosted-images/instagram.svg";
    document.getElementById('linkedin').src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mvt-hosted-images/linkedin.svg";
    document.getElementById('twitter').src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mvt-hosted-images/twitter.svg";

    //restores elements of the original homepage that were hidden for overlay
    pipe.style.display="block";
    contact.style.display="block";
    case_studies.style.display="block";

    $('#fp-menu .news').addClass("col-sm-2");
    $('#fp-menu .portfolio').addClass("col-sm-3");
    $('#fp-menu #social').addClass("col-sm-6");
};
```

I would expect that the function would trigger without the dev console being active. Please let me know if any further description or information would help.

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery and plain JS? Why not `$(".pipe").show();`?

Comment: Can you add your HTML and turn this into a Stack Snippet so we can execute it ourselves?

Comment: Why should `#social` change color? The only class you add to it is `col-sm-6`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar
I'm relatively new to jquery, and I'm trying to practice jquery as I go along. Eventually converting the entire script to jquery. 
I'll add the html today.
Social changes colour to accommodate the overlay feature, hopefully the html would make this clearer.